# How to add line break in a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a view that outputs in a document and the client send to the printer.

In a row there are too many text and i need to add a line break, like, after some quantity of characters.

Like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing" LINE BREAK 
"elit. Donec tincidunt mi nec dolor efficitur egestas."
```

But I need to apply this in a column to apply in all the data, past and future.

I can't update the data, just add a line break in the column in the view.

Comment: You can use CHAR(10) and CHAR(13)

Comment: how i can aplly this on a column? like CONTRATOITEM.PRODUTO in the view

Comment: Do you print data directly from SSMS? If not, I suggest you look into how this can be done in whatever software you are using to visualise the data. SQL Server does not have built in functionality to wrap text.

Comment: You need to provide more details... As far as I know you can use `SELECT CONTRATOITEM.PRODUTO + CHAR(10) AS [ColumnName], Column2...`

Comment: the text inside the CONTRATOITEM.PRODUTO need to be wraped

Comment: This kind of thing should be done in the front end, not the database. You are talking about formatting, not data retrieval.

Comment: A typical approach is to start _line width_ characters into the string, then work backwards looking for whitespace. Break the line, lather, rinse, repeat. That should make the lines no longer than _line width_ and split between words. You still need a fallback plan if that fails, e.g. due to a short _line width_ or a lengthy hyphenated phrase that needs to be split.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LineBreak (@input VARCHAR(max), @characters int)
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Work VARCHAR(max) = ''

    WHILE(LEN(@input) > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @Work = @Work + LEFT(@input, @characters);
        SET @input = SUBSTRING(@input, @characters+1, LEN(@input))
        IF @Input <> '' SET @Work = @Work + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)
    END

    RETURN @work
END
```

use:

```
 select dbo.linebreak('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tincidunt mi nec dolor efficitur egestas.', 10)
```

Comment: The first argument to [`substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should be `@input`, not `@input+1`. It's worth noting that no effort is made to break the line at whitespace.

Comment: Your function is not very efficient, but it also is invalid as posted. You are adding 1 to a varchar(max) parameter which doesn't work.